# Database Design to handle public and not public data

Tags: database-design

I'm working through a design. Currently we have a database that has content that gets "published". Meaning its available to the public. I've been asked to modify this process so that any additional changes to the data is not made public until that record is "re-published".

Currently, there is a flag that indicates if a record is published or not.

I would like to keep the records in one database as opposed to splitting into two.

are there any standard practices for this sort of scenario?

Thanks

TR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty basic example of an approval workflow. There are several different ways you can go about this, but it basically comes down to separating the published content, from the pending content. So for example, you would have a table that represents the fully published and public content. And then another table could hold pending changes for a record in the public table. Once an administrator or editor approves the changes, you can simply copy the contents of the now-approved record into the public table.

You can get way more complicated than this with ways to track multiple versions of a document, drafts, etc. ... but they're all extensions of the same principle: separating public from pending.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently, there is a flag that indicates if a record is published or not.

Fine.  Add values for modified and re-published.

Comment: Add the flags and store the modifications in other table(s)?

Comment: @TeddyRuxpin: You didn't say that you wanted to maintain a history of the changes in your question.  You'll need to add an added / modified timestamp column to the table.  Index by timestamp descending so that the most recent version is retrieved first.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Thanks for the quick comment